# Extjs add to combobox unselectable="on" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I want to set in combobox attribute `unselectable="on".` How can i do it in the javascript or jquery?

```
Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.HR = Ext.extend(Ext.util.Observable, {
init:function (cmp) {
    this.cmp = cmp;

    // create the combo instance
    this.combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        typeAhead:true,
        enableKeyEvents:false,
        triggerAction:'all',
        lazyRender:true,
        mode:'local',
        store:[8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 26, 28, 32, 36, 40, 48, 54, 60, 72],
        width:50,
        listeners:{
            scope:cmp,
            select:changeFont
        }

    });
    this.cmp.on('render', this.onRender, this);
},
onRender:function () {
    this.cmp.getToolbar().add(this.combo);
}
```

});

Thanks.

Comment: get reference to the element(s) and call `elem.setAttribute("unselectable", "on")`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setAttribute'

Comment: That's not a reference to the element then

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in ExtJS, why don't use just use:

```
Ext.get('someElemName').unselectable();
```